# How do I supply PartitionKey for RegisterObserverFactoryAsync function in Cosmos DB Change Feed processor?

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I am running the Change Feed Processor sample from the path https://github.com/Azure/azure-documentdb-dotnet/tree/master/samples/ChangeFeedMigrationTool as is. I have only changed the required key values in the App.config file to point to my Cosmos DB.

When I run this sample against partitioned collection, I get exception while registering the observer factory.

```
await host.RegisterObserverFactoryAsync(docObserverFactory);
```

The exception details:

```
InvalidOperationException: PartitionKey value must be supplied for this operation.

   at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Client.DocumentClient.<AddPartitionKeyInformationAsync>d__34f.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
...
at ChangeFeedMigrationSample.Program.<RunChangeFeedHostAsync>d__18.MoveNext() in D:\temp\samples\code-samples\ChangeFeedProcessor\Program.cs:line 181
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at ChangeFeedMigrationSample.Program.<MainAsync>d__16.MoveNext() in D:\temp\samples\code-samples\ChangeFeedProcessor\Program.cs:line 92
```

But the function does not accept any partition key. And I don't know how to pass one. Am I missing anything in this? Also, my understanding is Cosmos DB Change Feed Processor library manages all partitions implicitly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is lease collection partitioned? Partitioned lease collection is not currently supported (should be soon), and error message would be something like this. Can you try using single-partition lease collection.

Comment: Yes it works with a non-partitioned lease collection. Thank you.

Comment: Update: recent versions of CFP support partitioned lease collections. Out of the box, lease collection must be partitioned as /id, but it's possible to use any custom partitioning if you implement ILeaseStoreManager interface and use it with ChangeFeedProcessorBuilder.WithLeaseStoreManager().