# Function was unable to start. Microsoft.Azure.DocumentDB.Core: PartitionKey value must be supplied for this operation.?

Tags: node.js, typescript, azure, azure-functions, azure-cosmosdb

I have a simple azure function cosmos trigger set up, like so:

```
{
  "bindings": [
    {
      "type": "cosmosDBTrigger",
      "name": "documents",
      "direction": "in",
      "leaseCollectionName": "leases",
      "connectionStringSetting": "DbConnectionString",
      "databaseName": "mydb",
      "collectionName": "mycollection",
      "createLeaseCollectionIfNotExists": "true"
    }
  ],
  "scriptFile": "../dist/TestCosmosTrigger/index.js"
}
```

When I run the function I get an error:

> The listener for function 'Functions.FeedNotifier' was unable to
>   start. Microsoft.Azure.Documents.ChangeFeedProcessor: Host was already
>   initialized.

I did try to add a partitionKey field to th ebindings to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be related to this [issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-core-tools/issues/930). Try  with `single-partition lease collection` and also mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46821204/how-do-i-supply-partitionkey-for-registerobserverfactoryasync-function-in-cosmos)

Comment: I looked at those links, still not sure what to do? How do I try with single-partition lease collection?

Answer (score 0):

Please update to the latest `Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.CosmosDB` dependency [package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.CosmosDB).

This error either means you have a partitioned leases collection that is not partitioned by `/id` or you are using an old extension version.